# Get username using parent_id as user_id laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send an email with providing username but where parent_id exist it does not have username in that case we will pick parent_id = user_id it mean user_id = 3 having username parent.

So how can achieve this with ease.

```
User_id     parent_id        email          username
1                abc@gmail.com      abc
2                xyz@gmail.com      xyz
3       5        data@gmail.com     
4                nod@gmail.com      nodata
5                getPar@gmail.com   parent
```

I have done so far

```
$user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))
        ->where('type', Input::get('type'))
        ->active()
        ->first();
$data = [
            'name'     => $user->name,
            'email'    => $user->email,
            'username' => $user->username
        ];


Mail::later(5, 'emails.send', $data, function($message) use ($user)
        {
            $message->from('n-r@abc.com', 'abc');
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('ABC - Recovered Username');
        });

return Response::json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Recovered Username',
            'data'    => [
                'username' => $user->username
            ]
        ], 200);
```

On such requirement want to fetch that data where username is == '' && parent_id avail than send the email to that user who has parent_id = user_id in this above example parent_id = 5 than user_id will be = 5 so if someone invoke this than it should email to getPar@gmail.com along with its username

```
public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'parent_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Comment: Create a relationship for parent `$this->belongsTo('App\User', 'parent_id');`

Comment: already created in user model how to use this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence --> This should solve your dilemma